# Using SQLCommand - Will it dispose of items passed to strings?

Tags: c#, dispose, sqlcommand

I'm doing some SQL connections with the 'using' command to dispose/close connections for me. If I pass items to a string from within the using command, will they remain once the connection is closed/disposed?

If it does, what is the best way to make sure items are kept in the string rather than being disposed so that I can use them later on.

Comment: show some code to know that how are you doing and what doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are always passed by value. So, if I understand your question correctly, your strings should stay untouched. using statement will only dispose the command.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions just wanted clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you mean objects passed as the commands parameters? As far as I know they are not disposed when the command is disposed. The easiest way to make sure they are correctly dispose is to manually access the `SqlCommand.Parameters`.

For example, you can use the following code.

```
if (command.Parameters != null)
{
    foreach (object parameter in command.Parameters)
    {
        IDisposable disposableParameter = parameter as IDisposable;
        if (disposableParameter != null)
        {
            disposableParameter.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mess up several concepts. 
When you construct an SQL query you have 2 options, construct it using a string, like:

```
"Select from " + TableName + " where " + ColumnName + "=" + ColumnValue ...
```

**Very bad!** Never do this, you have to use parameters, like:

```
"Select from " + "TableName + " where " + ColumnName + "=@Value"
```

And after inject the value of interest using [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

**In both cases the lifetime of the actual value has nothing to do with a SQL string**. 
The value lifetime depends how you use a variable that holds that value.

Hope this helps.